# New React Native project with old version of react native

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a new react native project which should utilize an older version of react-native.

The result I would like would be to do something like: `react-native init MyProject` but have the version of react-native it uses be `0.13.2`.

However, there doesn't seem to be any options with `react-native-cli` for initializing with old versions of react-native.

Performing `react-native init MyProject` and then dowgrading react-native in `package.json` also does not work because the `init` command installs a bunch of xcode templates which are used to build the app and there is no `dowgrade` command which will dowgrade these templates. (There is an `upgrade` command.)

I tried downgrading my version of react-native-cli to `0.1.4` which was current when react-native `0.13` was current, but this did not work. From looking at the cli source, it seems it always initializes with just the newest version of react-native.

I realize this is pretty weird to want to start a new project at an old version, but I have a weird set of requirements that are forcing this.

Comment: AFAIK, I couldn't find some kind of 'downgrade of react-native'.
But when you init a project, `$ react-native init ProjectName --version 0.39.0` ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/react-native-cli/index.js#L51

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is a new parameter in `react-native init` that allows just this. Try:

```
react-native init --version="react-native@0.36.0" MyNewApp
```

Here my [source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4723). I have successfully tested it with `react-native-cli` 2.0.1.

Comment: nice answer.it helped.

Comment: this did not help me. instead react-native init newproject --version X.XX.X worked for me

Comment: works, but the app run with errors

Answer (score 39):

[`rninit`](https://github.com/jacobbubu/rninit) is a replacement for `react-native init` that allows you to specify a particular version of react-native to use.

Install `rninit` globally:

```
npm install -g rninit
```

Specify which version of react-native to use:

```
rninit init [Project Name] --source react-native@0.14.2
```

Thanks to @vanson-wing-leung for pointing me to `rninit`

Comment: Or just `react-native init blank --version react-native@0.14.2`.

Comment: @daserge this should be the accepted answer. I've just tried it with init blank --version react-native@0.24.0 and it worked as expected. Maybe move it outside the comments so OP can accept it?

Comment: Indeed, react-native seems to be able to handle this on it's own.

Comment: Is it the method to create a new project or redefining the version for the existing project ?

Comment: Didn't worked with latest react native cli

Comment: 12 dec 2023, this is the perfect solution to install rnv -70

Answer (score 27):

Use the `--version` flag.

```
react-native init blank --version react-native@0.14.2
```

Comment: use this instead react-native init newproject --version X.XX.X

Answer (score 7):

Here's the command as of April 2022.

`npx react-native init newproject --version="0.66.4"`

Comment: only this one works

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

If you install the version of `react-native` that you want in your project, you can then navigate to `(project)/node_modules/react-native/local-cli`. Here you will see three `generator` folders which enclose the exact files RN would have used to initiate a project.

It's a bit manual, but at least you'll have access to the original files.

Comment: This is a good start, thanks! I have formally submitted an issue to react native asking for native support of this feature. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4723

Answer (score 2):

specify react-native version at the time of installing

something like this

```
react-native init --version="react-native@0.52.0" ExampleApp
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that works with react native latest cli is

```
react-native init NewProject --version X.XX.X
```

e.g

```
react-native init NewProject --version 0.61.5
```

Thanks @Shamendra

Answer (score 1):

To use the same version of CLI to install React Native, you can use:

```
npx react-native@0.60.0 init rn60 --version="0.60.0"
```

output:

```
Need to install the following packages:
  react-native@0.60.0
Ok to proceed? (y)


               ######                ######
             ###     ####        ####     ###
            ##          ###    ###          ##
            ##             ####             ##
            ##             ####             ##
            ##           ##    ##           ##
            ##         ###      ###         ##
             ##  ########################  ##
          ######    ###            ###    ######
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ##
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###
          ######    ###            ###    ######
             ##  ########################  ##
            ##         ###      ###         ##
            ##           ##    ##           ##
            ##             ####             ##
            ##             ####             ##
            ##          ###    ###          ##
             ###     ####        ####     ###
               ######                ######


                  Welcome to React Native!
                 Learn once, write anywhere.

✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✔ Installing dependencies
✔ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)

  Run instructions for iOS:
    • cd rn60 && react-native run-ios
    - or -
    • Open rn60/ios/rn60.xcworkspace in Xcode or run "xed -b ios"
    • Hit the Run button

  Run instructions for Android:
    • Have an Android emulator running (quickest way to get started), or a device connected.
    • cd rn60 && react-native run-android
```

test

```
$ cd rn60
$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "rn60",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.0" <----
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

react-native init MyApp --version react-native@0.58.6

Answer (score -1):

For existing react native project to downgrade run

```
npm install react-native@0.13.2
```

Then verify the version by running

```
react-native -version
```