# React-native-maps fail with wrong version

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

Making first steps with React Native. Trying to just get a map show in the simulator. Fails with :

*React native version mismatch*

*JavaScript version 0.54.4*

*Native version 0.55.2*

I am following the examples as they are found on [react-native.com](https://github.com/facebook/react-native) and the [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps)

```
create-react-native-app MyMap
cd MyMap
npm install react-native-maps --save
vi App.js
```

add `import MapView from 'react-native-maps';`

add

```
<MapView
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}
  />
```

`npm run ios`

fails with the above error in the simulator. In the terminal it tells me that maps require `react-native 0.52 - 0.54` whereas the most recent version that came with the default install is `0.55`.

ps. Running a fresh OSX 10.13.4 Parallels-VM for development. Not sure if that's an issue?
pps. Running the app without the maps edit works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing your project with older react-native version.

`react-native init --version="0.54.0" MyMap`

this might help:

[New React Native project with old version of react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211131/new-react-native-project-with-old-version-of-react-native)

Comment: I do not have `react-native` in my path. Do I have to do `create-react-native-app MyMap` and run `react-native` there? Or install `sudo npm -g install react-native@0.54` ?

Comment: just do `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli` and then `react-native init --version="0.54.0" MyMap`

Comment: Did it. Seems to work. Now I get "Native component for AirMap does not exist" . Running iOS simulator. Moving on. However, now I do not have the Expo tool when I do `react-native init`.

Comment: yeah thats one draw back using init you dont get to Expo tool with it -_-