# How to run an old version of react native

Tags: react-native

Just a quick question, how to run an existing older version of react native project. Lets say version 0.59.10 , without upgrading it. what would be the command line commands. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211131/new-react-native-project-with-old-version-of-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should navigate to project directory (if you aren't yet)

```
cd PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIRECTORY
```

run the following command to install the dependencies

```
npm install
```

then if the react-native version is 0.59.10 and lowers you should also run the command below to link the dependencies to your native android and ios project.

```
react-native link
```

and then run one the following commands based on your device

for android

```
react-native run-android
```

for ios

```
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Its an existing project that I want to run on my device after `npm install` command. I should have been more details.

Comment: I have changed my answer based on What I got from your edited question, hope it help.